# I can't call fragment method from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Can somebody explain what is the problem here? The error is bellow:

Code in MainAcitivity:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
SvePonudeFragment fragment = (SvePonudeFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.ponudice);
fragment.reloadData();
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class SvePonudeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sve_ponude_fragment, container, false);

        rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        ArrayList<Ponuda> listaPonuda = null;
        initializeAdapter(listaPonuda);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initializeAdapter(List<Ponuda> preuzetePonude){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(preuzetePonude);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void reloadData(){
        System.out.println("I ENTEEERED");
    }

}
```

XML of fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ponudice">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is wrong with this? Can somebody explain me?
this is the error:

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   W/System.err:     at com.example.filip.dajsve.Activities.MainActivity.onDataLoaded(MainActivity.java:190)
>       W/System.err:     at com.example.filip.dajsve.Loaders.DatabaseDataLoader.loadData(DatabaseDataLoader.java:22)

Comment: Post your `MainActivity` class please

Comment: before calling `reloadData();` add `Log.d("MyApp", "is null = " + (fragment==null?"null":"not null"));` and run again. And then tell us if your fragment is null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem is that you don't link your fragment with mainActivity. first you should add your fragment in xml of mainActivty and give the fragment an id then access it in the main activity with the id of fragment not using this id `android:id="@+id/ponudice">` because this id related with relative layout not the fragment. check the xml code of main activity you should find fragment tags like code below

```
    <fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="theNameOfYourPackage.theNameOfFragment"
    android:id="@+id/ponudice_in_main_activity"/>
```

Comment: This is not the problem. Visit the following link to know more about fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
SvePonudeFragment fragment = new SvePonudeFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framecontainer,fragment).commit();
```

and your activity_main.xml file will be

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/framecontainer"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
>

</FrameLayout>
```